# В контактной форме не переведён пункт “My question was closed”

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, контактная-форма

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. > My question was closed
2. > Why is my question closed?
3. > Questions that need additional work or that are not a good fit for this site may be closed by experienced community members. While questions are closed, they can be edited to make them eligible for reopening.

Comment: Предложил варианты, поаппрувите?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica подправил и принял. В следующем обновлении появятся.

Comment: А я где-то допустил ошибку?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica в первой фазе точка не нужна, во второй слишком много "чтобы" и т.п. Обычно такое заменяю причастными оборотами)